# Capturar valor confirm con php

Tags: php, javascript

Mi problema es que pulse cancelar o pulse aceptar en el confirm, me entra de todas maneras en el if.

```
$comparar = true;
$comparar_js = "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('¿Borrar?')</script>";

echo($comparar_js);

if($comparar==$comparar_js){

   echo("Hola");
}else{

   echo("No entra en el if");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu planteamiento está mal.

No puedes pasar directamente el valor de `JS` del lado cliente a `PHP` del lado servidor.

Y te da `true` porque estás comparando `true == 'cadenaLlena'` [<= Ver online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70f2b2bc3a684c02ab3812b5e519eccd2ccf134d)

Ejemplo:

Al presionar el botón borrar te sale la alerta y lo confirmas o no y te lleva a la página donde quieres que se ejecuta la petición:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function borrar() {
    return window.confirm( '¿Borrar?' );
  }
</script>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ]; ?>" onsubmit="return borrar()" method="post">
  <!-- tus otros inputs -->
  <input type="submit" name="submitBorrar" value="Borrar">
</form>
```

Luego para comprobar si se ha hecho la petición `borrar` (tu condición):

```
<?php
// Comprueba si esta establecido el submit `submitBorrar`
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submitBorrar' ] ) ) {

  $txt = 'Borramos';
}
else {

  $txt = 'No entra en el if';
}

echo $txt;
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacer algo así.

Este es un error muy típico en gente que pasa de la programación de aplicaciones de escritorio a programación web (no sé si es tu caso).

Lo que hay que tener muy claro en la programación web es que tienes dos entornos diferentes de ejecución de código, que ejecutan código en entornos completamente separados (la mayoría de las veces incluso físicamente: equipo servidor y equipo cliente con el navegador) y en momentos diferentes.

Tienes que tener siempre en mente el ciclo de vida de una petición web:

1. El navegador realiza una solicitud de una página web al servidor
2. En el servidor se ejecuta el código de servidor (en tu caso PHP) que genera el código (HTML, javascript, css) que debe enviar al cliente. Así que, básicamente, el código PHP es código que genera código. Pero no ejecuta este código generado, si no que lo envía al navegador para que sea él quien lo ejecute.
3. El servidor envía el código (HTML, Javascript, CSS) generado al navegador
4. El navegador interpreta y ejecuta el código recibido y muestra el resultado

Este es el motivo por el que desde tu código PHP, que se está ejecutando en el servidor en el momento 2, no puedes acceder al resultado del código Javascript que se ejecuta en el navegador en el momento 4.

En tu caso, el código PHP lo que haría es crear la siguiente salida para enviar al navegador:

```
$comparar = true;
$comparar_js = "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('¿Borrar?')</script>";
echo($comparar_js); // Salida: "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm(...
if($comparar==$comparar_js){ // Si true=="<script type='text...."
    echo("Hola"); // Esto no se puede dar nunca
}else{
    echo("No entra en el if"); // Salida: "No entra en el if"
}
```

Lo que se envía al navegador es por tanto:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('¿Borrar?')</script>
No entra en el if
```

Es decir mostraré un diálogo `confirm` con el texto `¿Borrar?` con cuyo resultado no se hace nada y muestra en el navegador sí o sí el mensaje `No entra en el if`.

Espero que te sirva para aclarar algunas ideas.